# Laravel migration: adding foreign key to the same table where ID is a string

Tags: laravel, migration, key

I'm trying to make "categories" migration, where each category refers it's parent category by ID in the same table.

Migration:

```
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id', 36)->primary();

        $table->string('parent_id', 36)->nullable();
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

        $table->string('name');
    });
```

But i'm getting next error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `categories` add constraint `categories_parent_id_foreign` foreign key (`parent_id`) references `categories` (`id`))

Field types are the same, and I don't know, what to do.
Removing "->nullable()" has no effect.

Laravel Framework version 6.20.7

Thanks.

Comment: You have parent table in database?

Comment: Irshad, table are the same, this is one migration for all.

Comment: Unflux, if you told about "$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->nullable();" - no, the same error.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what version of Laravel btw?

Comment: @lagbox thx, `Laravel Framework 6.20.7`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add the foreign key constraint in another run like as below

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id', 36)->primary();

            $table->string('parent_id', 36)->nullable();

            $table->string('name');
    });

    Schema::table('categories',function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a strange but working way to achieve it!

Comment: Is not a strange issue because you are trying to allocate the foreign key to a table which does not exists yet (which is categories table and while creating it you try to reference the foreign key to the table it self which is not yet created but in creating status...)